# Disable Dynamically generated buttons in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code which runs on form's load event. In which, row and column are variable and can have different values every time form loads.

```
    Dim XPos, YPos As Integer
    Dim btn As Button
    XPos = 80
    YPos = 80
    For i = 1 To row
        XPos = 150
        For j = 1 To column
           btn = New Button
           btn.Name = "btn" & i & j
           btn.Size = New Drawing.Size(40, 40)
           btn.Location = New Point(XPos, YPos)
           Me.Controls.Add(btn)
           XPos = XPos + btn.Width + 5
        Next
        YPos = YPos + btn.Height + 5
    Next
```

Suppose, row=5 and column=5 then output will be like

```
btn11  btn12  btn13  btn14  btn15
btn21  btn22  btn23  btn24  btn25
btn31  btn32  btn33  btn34  btn35
btn41  btn42  btn43  btn44  btn45
btn51  btn52  btn53  btn54  btn55
```

Now, If I click on btn32 then I can click only on its adjacent buttons like:
btn21,btn22,btn23,btn31,btn33,btn41,btn42,btn43 and I can't click on rest of the buttons.

If I click first on btn54 after then I will be only able to click on btn53,btn43,bt44mbtn45,btn55 , I will not be able to click on rest of buttons.

And rest of the buttons should be remained in same style(colour,text.. etc)

How to disable those rest of the buttons. Help me here...

Comment: First disable all buttons, then extract the column and row of the clicked button. After that just check if there is any buttons in `curC - 1, curR - 1` and `curC, curR - 1` and `curC + 1, curR - 1` and `curC - 1, curR` and `curC + 1, curR` and so on, and enable them (where `curC` is the current column and `curR` the current row).

Comment: The top left button will be at position `Current Column - 1, Current Row - 1` and the bottom right button will be at position `Current Column + 1, Current Row + 1`.

Comment: Can you tell me the code that how can I enable them?

Comment: `.Enabled = True`? Just loop through all controls in `Me.Controls` and check their type.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting the row and column of the clicked button like suggested by Visual Vincent, you could store them in properties of the object itself.
Then, like described already - iterate through `Me.Controls` and disable everything which is a button and whose row and column property isn't fitting the requirement to leave enabled.

```
Class GenBtn
    Inherits Button
    Private row, col As Integer
    Public Function isAdjacent(ByRef Column As Integer, ByRef Row As Integer)
        If Column < Me.col - 1 Or Column > Me.col + 1 Then
            Return False
        ElseIf Row < Me.row - 1 Or Row > Me.row + 1 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**Tip:** Group the controls to easily point only to the generated controls without accidently disabling main elements.

Comment: Good answer. But don't loop it, that's a waste of CPU and memory if the columns and rows are stored within the buttons' name.

Comment: Also, why check if it's outside the bounds? Check if it's inside instead with a single statement: `Return (Column >= Me.col - 1 AndAlso Column <= Me.col + 1 AndAlso Row >= Me.row - 1 AndAlso Row <= Me.row + 1)`

Comment: @VisualVincent I agree. This Statement makes it quite smaller and smarter. Only wanted to ppint to inheritance instead of calculating the positions by name and total columns. I think Yash Mehta now should consider his use case.

Comment: Now, I got it. Thank you so much